# C# .NET 6, implementation of concurrent throttling tool

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to seek advice on my implementation of rate controlling or throtting tool which implemented by C#.NET 6.

1. correctness of implementation
2. performance issue or any improvement
   can be done.

---

```
public sealed class RateLimiter : IDisposable
{
    private const string KEY = "RL";

    private readonly Timer _timer;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte> _token = new();

    public RateLimiter(TimeSpan window, int limit)
    {
        double total = window.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (total <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("window can not be zero or negative", nameof(window));
        }

        if (limit <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("limit can not be zero or negative", nameof(limit));
        }

        double interval = total / limit;

        _timer = new Timer(interval);
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _token.TryAdd(KEY, byte.MinValue);
    }

    public bool TryAcquire()
    {
        return _token.TryRemove(KEY, out _);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Close();
    }
}
```

---

Use case:

```
// create RateLimiter instance, set the rate to be 10 messages per second

_throttle = new RateLimiter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 10);

// if within limit, then publish price

if (_throttle.TryAcquire())
{
    // publish stock price to downstream
}
```

Comment: Do you have a usage example and/or unit tests that help reviewers understand how this class is intended to be used?  That might help you get better answers.

Comment: FYI: [Announcing Rate Limiting for .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That's why I mentioned .NET 6 explicitly :)

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor and use case comment are at least confusing if not incorrect. I first thought I can just send 10 requests per second, but that's not really true looking at the code. If wanted to send all of them in the first 10% of the second, I wouldn't be able to and only the first one would pass.

In reality, you allow sending 1 request per 0.1ms. If your primary constructor already passed the `interval` value of `TimeSpan` only, that would make your API less confusing and your code simpler. Constructing interval from your "window" and "limit" can then be your secondary more sophisticated option of creating the object. I would name and document it more carefully though.

Answer (score 1):

### Some Terminology

First of all let's start with some terminology, because I can see a lots of confusion here. There are *rate limiters* and *rate gates*.

#### Similarity

- Both concepts can be used to throttle requests.
- They sit between the clients and the server and they know about the server's capacity.

#### Difference

- The limiter, as its name implies, limits the traffic. It short-cuts the requests if there are too many.
- The gate on the other hand holds/delays the requests until there is enough capacity.

#### Algorithms

- The rate limiter usually implements the [leaky-bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) or [token-bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithm

  - For example Polly's [ratelimiter](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/c27faf89ef459fd9a8e0131ae1d4cd835ca4f31d/src/Polly/RateLimit/LockFreeTokenBucketRateLimiter.cs) implements token bucket
- The rate gate usually utilizies some queuing mechanism with timers

  - [Sample implementation](https://github.com/QuantConnect/Lean/blob/f3c386663be9461788a443a72a4796141aaa4ba9/Common/Util/RateGate.cs)

---

### Back to your code

- Quite frankly I can not tell with confidence which one do you want to implement

  - I can only guess
- You are using a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store and remove the exact same key and value over and over again

  - This structure seems to me a bit overkill for the above purpose
- I don't understanding the concept behind the `TryAcquire`

  - Anyone can ignore the result of this method so (s)he can perform any number of actions without any constraint
- Even in your sample usage code you are not wrapping your `RateLimiter` in a `using` block then how could you expect that consumer of your util will do?